# how to use variable in image src ionic

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

how can i use {{ }} in src of a image?
i got error with this code near [src]

```
    <ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of results| async">
    <ion-thumbnail slot="start">
      <ion-img [src]={{ item.qrlink }}></ion-img>
    </ion-thumbnail>
    <ion-label>{{ item.Title }}</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

in the page.ts i have this code:

```
 submit_newcheck()
  {
  this.results = this.encryptionService.newcheck(this.checkid,this.cost,this.toname,this.tocode,this.passcode,this.date );

  }
```

which is connected to a service like this:

```
export class EncryptionService {
     constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    newcheck(checkid: string ,cost: string,toname: string,tocode: string,passcode: string,date: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`https://api.test.com/encrypte.php?checkid=${encodeURI(checkid)}&&cost=${encodeURI(cost)}&&toname=${encodeURI(toname)}&&tocode=${encodeURI(tocode)}&&passcode=${encodeURI(passcode)}&&date=${encodeURI(date)}`).pipe(
      map(results => results['Data'])
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be either be `[src]="item.qrlink"` or `src={{ item.qrlink }}`. They aren't supposed to be mixed together.

**Explanation**

In case of `[src]="item.qrlink"` the value of variable `item.qrlink` is bound to the `[src]` property using property binding. Read up more on template expression [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-expressions).

In case of `src={{ item.qrlink }}` the value `item.qrlink` is interpolated and assigned to the attribute `src`. Read up more on interpolation [here](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#interpolation-).